# is it possible to use pandas objects with rpy2?

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I'd like to use pandas in combination with R, so I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]},index=["one", "two"])
>>> robjects.r.cor(df.A, df.B)
    ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> at the moment.
```

Does this mean I cannot yet use pandas' objects with rpy2?

I then tried:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]},index=["one", "two"])
rdf = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

But how would I do the above with `rdf`? For instance, `rdf['A']` gives me a `TypeError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is initial support to make have a seamless use of pandas and R/rpy.

You'll need to do:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

The documentation is a little behind, and the support is not complete, but there is small example to show where this is heading:

https://plus.google.com/116424798545383828852/posts/jPfZ8VcTVi3

Comment: this is a nice example for the cookbook: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html ; also a link in the R section of the docs would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df.corr('pearson')
=> A  B
A  1  1
B  1  1
stats.f_oneway(df['A'], df['B'])
=> (13.5, 0.021311641128756723)
```

I know this doesn't answer your question exactly, but sometimes running into issues like this indicates that you are not using the tools as they are intended.

Comment: Because I will eventually use more complicated statistical tests (e.g., ANOVAs) that are currently not implemented in pandas as far as I'm aware. The example povided was only for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I added an anova using scipy. There is very little you can do in R that you can't do in python. My understanding of rpy is that it is for running R modules within python, not really for writing R code in the python interpreter. Feel free to prove me wrong! This is just my understanding.

Comment: @mattexx While the assertion that there is little you can do in R cannot be achieved in Python is technically true )since Python is a programming language), it neglects an important point: how much effort it might take you to achieve the same result. At this point in time, R might just have the most comprehensive library of statistical tools.

Comment: @mattexx (cont.) Regarding rpy(2), it exposes all of R to Python. This gives the ability to run function in R but also to parse and evaluate strings with R code. Pushing this far gave the enticing "rmagic" in iPython (with which once can literally write R code in a Python interactive session).

Comment: @HappyPy You will find ANOVA in the statsmodels package. There's an extended example [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_interactions.html)